# Закрыть уязвимость CVE-2014-0224?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, openssl

Здравствуйте. Как закрыть уязвимость для моего VPS сервера (Ubuntu 14.04 + Apache 2.4.7)?

Сайт https://www.ssllabs.com/ сообщает:

> "This server is vulnerable to the OpenSSL CCS vulnerability
> (CVE-2014-0224) and exploitable. Grade set to F."

Но у меня уже установлен свежий OpenSSL:

> user@mydomain:~# openssl version
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

А проблема та же...

Comment: Покажите выводы `dpkg -s openssl` и `dpkg -s libssl-dev` . И проверьте какие версии использует именно веб-сервер.

Comment: dpkg -s openssl выдал следующее: Package: openssl
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 1118
Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.0.2g-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libssl1.0.2 (>= 1.0.2g)
Suggests: ca-certificates

Comment: dpkg -s libssl-dev
Package: libssl-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 6162
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: openssl
Version: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2
Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2), zlib1g-dev
Recommends: libssl-doc

Comment: Если Nginx используется, покажите вывод nginx -V. Ну и можно подробную информацию об апаче.

Comment: Nginx не используем. Только Apache. Apache -v: 
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr  3 2014 12:20:28

Comment: Проблема решена переустановкой OpenSSL на версию 1.0.1f и Apache на 2.4.20 !